# Adding script.max_size_in_bytes: 10000000 is not considered in elastisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

Default value of **max_size_in_bytes** in elastic 6.5 seems to be `16384` . I am using a [wyomind magneto 2](https://www.wyomind.com/fr/magento2/elastic-search-magento.html) search plugin which is throwing following issue if search result contains a lot of data. If search result contains less data, it works fine.

> Scripts may be no longer than 16384 characters.  The passed in script
>   is 21878 characters.  Consider using a plugin if a script longer than
>   this length is a requirement.

I have added `script.max_size_in_bytes: 10000000` in elasticsearch.yml and restarted it. Still I am getting above error.

Comment: It looks like it's going to be fixed in ES 6.6: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/35184

Comment: Correct. How I can configure it in 6.5 as adding it to elasticsearch.yml isn't working and default value is still used. Where can I update it?

Comment: In 6.5 you cannot lift that limit as [it is hardcoded](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.5/modules/lang-painless/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/painless/Compiler.java#L55). The limit [has been lifted in ES 6.6](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.6/modules/lang-painless/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/painless/Compiler.java). The `max_size_in_bytes` setting is something different.

Comment: It seems 6.6 is not released yet. Is there any alternative to fix it as I need to diseable whole search module which has multiple customisation.

Comment: 6.6 isn't out yet, but the branch has been created already (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/6.6), so I'd just wait for the release. Or you could rewrite your script to be more compact maybe?

Comment: Ok. What is the expected release date for 6.6 ? Is it possible to install beta/dev/pre-release (6.6) version ?